# How to calculate route distance from current location to destination point in Android with Array list

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, location, android-gps, google-distancematrix-api

I have all latitude and longitude  of the route and i store them in Array List . My problem  is to calculate distance from current location to  destination location not straight line instead of using lat and long list to calculate the total distance.

The user may on application when they at the middle of the route , how we check the direction of the user in which direction they travel and also want to show direction arrow to guide the user to path to reached at the end of destination.

I have following route list coordinates

```
 private List<LatLng>Route_data=new ArrayList<>();
 Route_data.add(new LatLng(26.4178639682,45.1525075372))
 Route_data.add(new LatLng(26.4180316260,45.1525486342))
 Route_data.add(new LatLng(26.4187514397,45.1524630683))
 Route_data.add(new LatLng(26.4187286584,45.1521783630))
 Route_data.add(new LatLng(26.4185696655,45.1519302694))
 Route_data.add(new LatLng(26.4182746231,45.1515815804))
 Route_data.add(new LatLng(26.4190233717,45.1513697017))

 Double  totaldistance = Math.round(SphericalUtil.computeLength(Route_data));
```

i have calculated the total distance of the route by using this function , the problem is how we calculate distance from current user location to route data .
for example if user current location is received on the middle of the route , how i calculate distance to end of the route path .

```
 Double  totaldistanceremaing = Math.round(SphericalUtil.computeLength(new LatLng(currentuserlat, currentuserlang),Route_data));
```

How i make this type of function that is return remaining distance from current location to route list point not a straight line  current location to end point rather use all way point that is middle .Used Array list to calculate distance .

second question i want to asked how i show navigation to user follow the path direction . i

Note :  i am not want to used direction API because it offline app that work without internet . recommended good way to solved this problem . Thanks